# How to make Windows 8.1 not losing drivers after reset?

Tags: windows, drivers

So if I do a " full reset PC" in the settings, all my drivers will lost, but on a Windows 10 system it won't, there's actually a automatic "installing drivers" stage after reset, how do I archive this on Windows 8.1?

Comment: You would have to modify the .wim used during a Reset and slipstream drivers into the .wim file.

Comment: If you don't mind me suggesting a viable alternative: I backup the `%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\DriverStore` folder on each of my Windows machines to an external USB drive, typically once a month. If I ever need to reinstall Windows under any circumstances that results in missing device drivers, I can temporarily attach that USB drive, open `Device Manager`, right-click the unknown device, select `Update driver software...` and point it at the *DriverStore* folder on the USB drive. This will search through the folder hierarchy and install the missing driver. Repeat for each unknown device.